# Handling multiple client's file descriptors C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client-server

I'm working on a exam project, witch is a server/client application in C with OS Linux. The server needs to send a request to every connected client and then it grabs only one response, from the first client to answer. Now how do I keep track of all the connected client? I'm using the call accept() to get a file descriptor for talking to a new client, but I dont get how to store multiple of them in a proper way. Also ho do i get only the first response and trash all the others?

Comment: If you need to handle multiple clients you should probably use [select](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). About the second part, do you close the connection with the others clients that were not first to send an answer?

Comment: An array or other data structure to hold all the clients information.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont get how to store multiple of them in a proper way.

If you have an exam project to build a client / server system then you must already be well versed in C compound data types such as arrays, and data structures such as linked lists.  In that light, the fact that you asked the question leads me to think that you have a misunderstanding of file descriptors.

Specifically, you must be assuming that there is some kind of significance to their storage location, but this is not the case.  File descriptors are just values, not objects -- you can store them in any suitable object (variable, structure member, array element), copy them to other objects, exchange them with functions via arguments and return values, *etc*..

Thus, there is no single "proper" way to store your file descriptors.  You can use any data type or structure that suits your purposes.  For instance, if you have a structure representing data about a connected client, then I would probably expect those data to include the file descriptor for its connection (but that does not necessarily need to be the only place it is stored).

> Also ho [sic] do i get only the first response and trash all the others?

That depends partly on how the server tracks and maintains the state of each client (multiple threads? multiple processes? I/O multiplexing with [`select()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`poll()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)?) and on the application-level protocol the clients and server use to communicate.  Basically, though, you maintain a flag somewhere that says whether to apply the next response that arrives or to just consume and discard it.